# join two tables in php file

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

i have two tables

```
users (users_id,name,password)
report(id,detailes,date,user_id(fk))
```

i want to insert data in `table (report)` and after insert data into report
it should report 1 belong to user 1 ..etc

and in second step hen user view report it must view
`name from table users`, and `detailes,date from report`

so i make the following step

make fk user_id in table 2

and i use the following php & query

```
    <?php

class DbOperation
{
    private $conn;

    //Constructor
    function __construct()
    {
        require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/Config.php';
        require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/DbConnect.php';
        // opening db connection
        $db = new DbConnect();
        $this->conn = $db->connect();
    }

      //Function to add reports to the database
    public function addreports($id,$Detailes){
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO Reports (Detailes,users_id) VALUES (?,?,?)");
        $stmt->bind_param("si",$Detailes,$users_id);
        if($stmt->execute())
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    //Function to get reports & user details from the database
    public function getreports(){
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT Reports.Detailes,Reports.date users.name FROM Reports JOIN Reports where Reports.id = users_id;");
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        return $result;
    }

}
```

is my php & query in it is right or there is any error in join or anything?
this file i use to work phpmyadmin & android

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
SELECT
    Reports.Detailes,
    Reports.date,
    users.name
FROM
    Reports
JOIN 
    users 
ON 
   Reports.users_id = users.users_id;
```

Comment: okay i will try it , but i have question is other remainder of my php file is it okay? and my wrong only in join query?

Comment: and it will data in report will belong to users , i mean user by id=1 will have report 1 and user by id 2 will have report 2

Comment: you have many mistakes in your query  try to write formatted query.

Comment: just add WHERE users.user_id =1 at the end of query before semi colon ; 

I hope it will work fine

Comment: can you tell me where is my mistakes in php file.. and i cant add user_id=1 because i dont know who will registe, many user will be registe in application and any one registe should have report file

Comment: i have created a new function please check in new answer you will get the reports saved against user.

Answer (score 0):

Try this you will get the reports according to there users.

```
   public function getUserReports($userid = 0)
    {
      $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT Reports.Detailes, Reports.date, users.name FROM Reports JOIN users ON Reports.users_id = users.users_id WHERE users.user_id = ".$userid);
      $stmt->execute();
      $result = $stmt->get_result();
      return $result;
    }
```